# MySql Query for calculating Service uptime

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have two tables. In one table I maintain start and End time of the service. The 2nd table is transnational which contains Start and Stop time of service (0 means Stop and 1 means Start).
Need help on MySQL query on availability of service for a day or for specific range of date as below in hours:

```
Date      |ServiceId|Available|Not available
06-08-2020|189      | 10      |2
06-08-2020|187      | 8       |4
```

My Tables as below:

TblStatus

```
ServiceId|status|Updated_Date
189      |1     |04-08-2020 09:42
189      |0     |04-08-2020 12:29
189      |1     |04-08-2020 12:47
189      |0     |04-08-2020 13:37
189      |1     |04-08-2020 14:16
```

TblMaster

```
ServiceId|StartTime|EndTime
189      |09:00:00 |23:59:59
```

Comment: group by ServiceId and Available

Comment: It seems your data have inconsistency. You say in `TblMaster` it will be live between 9 and 23 which is 14 hours for id 189. but the sum of availability and unavailability is 12?? And if unavailability be hours between 0 and the next 1 status, your service 189 is less than 1 hour was unavailable.

Comment: It's an example given for the output

Comment: @ClaudioLopes How group by is going to help here? I need availability hours on the base of time stamps captured.

Comment: @Kartikeya my bad, wanted to say ServiceId and date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sort your dataset by service, updated_at asc
2. Create variables where you'll save the previous row you processed

You might need to track:
last_row_service_id
last_row_status
last_row_updated_date

3. Process dataset

```
    #pseudocode
    @SET last_row_service_id := -1;
    @SET last_row_status := -10; #set to -10 so that we wont have -1 or +1 value in first row
    @SET last_row_updated_date :='2020-08-06 00:00:00';
    
    select DATE(updated_date) as 'Date', serviceId as ServiceId,
    
    SUM(IF(@last_row_service_id = serviceId AND @last_row_status - status = 1, 
    
    #check if youre still on the same service and if last_row_status is 1 and current row status is 0
    
    TIME_TO_SEC(updated_date) - TIME_TO_SEC(@last_row_updated_date), 0)) as 'Available', 
    
    #Get elapsed time in seconds, else return 0 seconds
    
    # Do the same to 'Not available'
    
    SUM(IF(@last_row_service_id = serviceId AND @last_row_status - status = -1, 
    
    TIME_TO_SEC(updated_date) - TIME_TO_SEC(@last_row_updated_date), 0)) as 'Not available', 
    
    # change value of pointers
    
    @last_row_service_id := serviceId,
    @last_row_status := status,
    @last_row_updated_date := updated_date
    
    from TblStatus
    #Add your date filter
    group by DATE(updated_date),serviceId
```

You still need to handle service uptime that runs past 23:59:59

What you can do is to add START (status 1) event on every start of day and STOP (status 0) event on every end of day before processing.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Date(TS.Updated_Date) as Updated_Date, TM.ServiceId,
count(case when TS.Status=1 then 1 END) as Available, 
count(case when TS.Status=0 then 1 END) as NotAvailable
from TblMaster TM 
INNER JOIN TblStatus TS ON (TM.ServiceId = TS.ServiceId)
where TM.StartTime <= Time(TS.Updated_Date) and TM.EndTime >= Time(TS.Updated_Date)
group by Date(TS.Updated_Date),ServiceId;
```

Comment: Could you explain to OP  the logic from this query?